# Removing dot symbol from string - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to replace '.' symbol to '':

```
excel_data_df['serialNumber'] = df2[['Serial number', 'Serial number.1']].agg(''.join, axis=1).replace(to_replace = '.', value = '', regex = True)
```

My string: "TF013168."
Name: serialNumber, dtype: object, number saved as text in the excel.

But as the result I get all the characters removed from the string.
Is there any other way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Escape `.` by `\.`, because `.` is special regex character for replace substrings:

```
excel_data_df['serialNumber'] = df2[['Serial number', 'Serial number.1']].agg(''.join, axis=1).replace(to_replace = '\.', value = '', regex = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `regex=False` option of [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to prevent interpretation of `.` as an "any character" regex. No need to use a regex engine in your case. NB. the `regex=True` default is planned to be changed to `regex=False` in the future anyway.

```
excel_data_df['serialNumber'] = (df2[['Serial number', 'Serial number.1']]
                                 .agg(''.join, axis=1)
                                 .replace(to_replace='.', value='', regex=False)
```